# RESTeasy back-end - Restlet front-end : response entity null

Tags: http, gwt, jetty, restlet, resteasy

I have some REST services on my server (Jetty, RESTeasy) and a GWT client.
I choosed to use Restlet-GWT module on the front end.

I made a JSE client (RESTeasy client) and my service is well called (i see SQL trace in the log of Jetty server) and i get an xml response.

Then i tried from GWT with Restlet. The web service is called (Jetty log) but i have a null response.

Web service (Back end):

```java
@GET
@Path("/getArt/{id}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Art getArt(@PathParam("id")int id){
    Art art= artDAO.findById(id);
    return art;
}
```

Front-end GWT :

```java
public class Front_End implements EntryPoint {

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {    
final Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
client.get("http://localhost:8080/rest/service/getArt/1", new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Request request, Response response) {

        System.out.println("Reponse : " + response.getEntity().getText());
    }
});
}
```

RESTeasy client working :

```java
public Object test(int id){
    try {

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/rest/service/getArt/"+id);

        request.accept("application/xml");
        ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);

        if (response.getStatus() == 200) 
        {
            Unmarshaller un = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Object o = un.unmarshal(new StringReader(response.getEntity()));
            return o;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Are RESTeasy and Restlet "compatible" ? Should i use Restlet in the back end instead of RESTeasy ? What am i missing ?

Thx in advance

Comment: This should work fine, Restlet-GWT can talk to any HTTP server. If you do use Restlet on the server side, you can however benefit from some automatic bean serialization. Which version of Restlet are you using? What is the response returned by RESTeqsy to Restlet=GWT?

Comment: Thx for your answer, in fact i was having a SOP problem. It was not caused by Restlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a SOP issue.
My server was running on port 8080, and GWT on port 8888.

I used a proxy (put it in your /war in the client side) :

proxy.jsp

```
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%><%@page session="false"%>
<%@page import="java.net.*,java.io.*" %>

<%
try {
String reqUrl = request.getQueryString();
URL url = new URL(reqUrl.substring(4));

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
int clength = request.getContentLength();
if (clength > 0) {
    con.setDoInput(true);
    byte[] idata = new byte[clength];
    request.getInputStream().read(idata,0,clength);
    con.getOutputStream().write(idata,0,clength);
}
response.setContentType(con.getContentType());
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(line);
}
rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.setStatus(500);
}
%>
```

then in your class where you make the call, your url becomes :

```
String url ="proxy.jsp?url=" + URL.encode("http://localhost:8080/rest/service/getArt/1");
```

There is another way to solve it, check https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/Xsite

Comment: Great, btw the Restlet API comes with a Redirector class that helps you write such reverse proxy in a simpler way.